# How to have an an ALB point to the same application over 2 different protocols?

Tags: networking, https, terraform, amazon-ecs, aws-alb

I have an application that I am deploying to AWS on ECS using Terraform.  I would like to set it up so that it can perform a health check over HTTP, but require authentication and perform all other activities over HTTPS.  However, I have no idea how to set this up and nothing I'm trying is working.  Ideally, the HTTPS port should be 8080 (not sure if this is possible, if it's not please advise; it's not a big deal to use a different port).  The HTTP port would ideally also be 8080 but can be different as well (I know nothing about networking and not sure if I can hit the same port with 2 different protocols to access 2 different sets of endpoints).

Here's the most recent iteration of what I've tried (abbreviated to only show the parts I think are important); I've tried other things as well but this is the most recent:

```
resource "aws_ecs_service" "service" {
  name            = "${var.app_name}-service"
  cluster         = aws_ecs_cluster.main.id
  task_definition = aws_ecs_task_definition.app.arn
  desired_count   = var.app_count
  launch_type     = "FARGATE"
  health_check_grace_period_seconds = 240

  network_configuration {
    security_groups  = [var.security_group_id]
    subnets          = var.private_subnet_ids
    assign_public_ip = true
  }

  load_balancer {
    target_group_arn = aws_alb_target_group.app.id
    container_name   = var.app_name
    container_port   = var.app_port
  }

  depends_on = [aws_alb_listener.listener]
}

resource "aws_alb_target_group" "app" {
  name        = "${var.app_name}-target-group"
  port        = 443
  protocol    = "HTTPS"
  vpc_id      = var.vpc_id
  target_type = "ip"

  health_check {
    interval            = "30"
    protocol            = "HTTPS"
    matcher             = "200-299"
    timeout             = "3"
    path                = var.app_health_check_path
    unhealthy_threshold = "3"
  }
}

resource "aws_alb_listener" "listener" {
  load_balancer_arn = var.alb_arn
  port              = var.alb_listener_port
  protocol          = "HTTPS"
  ssl_policy        = "ELBSecurityPolicy-2016-08"
  certificate_arn   = var.ssl_cert

  default_action {
    type             = "fixed-response"
    fixed_response {
      content_type = "text/plain"
      message_body = "contact admin for ${var.app_name} access"
      status_code = 403
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "cf_auth_listener_rule" {
  listener_arn = aws_alb_listener.listener.arn
  priority     = 101

  action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_alb_target_group.app.arn
  }

  condition {
    http_header {
      http_header_name = <HEADER_NAME>
      values           = [<HEADER_VALUE>]
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "health_check_listener_rule" {
  listener_arn = aws_alb_listener.listener.arn
  priority     = 1

  action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_alb_target_group.app.arn
  }

  condition {
    path_pattern {
      values           = [var.app_health_check_path]
    }
  }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that my service is starting, but then immediately shutting down due to failed health check.  It seems the ALB can't contact the health check endpoint to perform the health check.

Comment: please post the errors you are getting

Comment: @ArunK I am not getting any errors, just my ECS tasks are crashing due to failed health check.

Comment: your health checks are using HTTPS, are you sure that your containers are running https and port 443.